# Windows Store App Certification Toolkit: The app bundle must be digitally signed

Tags: uwp, signing

When I try to run the Windows Store App Certification Toolkit on my UWP app, it fails with the exception message "The app bundle must be digitally signed".

I have associated the project with the app in Windows Store in Visual Studo. My understanding was that this should have created storekey.pfx. I don't see this anywhere.

Comment: Have you selected a certificate before you package your app? In step 4 of [Create an app package using the packaging wizard selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-using-the-packaging-wizard)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was it. I'd tried signing the assembly but not the package.